# How can I use fold with a Result return value?

Tags: error-handling, functional-programming, rust

I have a function:

```
fn test<T: FromStr>(text: &str) -> Result<T, SaleError>
```

`SaleError` is my custom error struct in this case.

I have 2 arrays that I want to multiply the same position values and sum the result:

```
fn calculate_result() -> Result<f64, SaleError> {
    let q_coms = ["1", "2", "3"];
    let v_un_coms = ["1", "2", "3"];
    Ok(try!(q_coms.iter().zip(v_un_coms.iter()).fold(0.0, mult_and_sum)))
}
```

The function tries to zip both arrays and than tries to call `fold` on the `mult_and_sum` function:

```
fn mult_and_sum(sum: f64, (q_com, v_un_com): (&str, &str)) -> Result<f64, SaleError> {
    Ok(sum + try!(test::<f64>(q_com)) * try!(test::<f64>(v_un_com)))
}
```

The problem, as far as I can understand, is that `fold` expects a function with the signature

```
fn mult_and_sum(sum: f64, (q_com, v_un_com): (&str, &str)) -> f64
```

Since the `test` function can fail, how can I use `fold` with a `Result` return value so if it fails, `calculate_result` will return `Err(SaleError)`?

Comment: Amusingly, I have a [PR to add that support directly to `Result`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/38580).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to guess, the error message tells you. I've reorganized it to make it more obvious:

```
actual:   for<'r, 'r> std::ops::FnMut<(f64, (&'r str, &'r str))>
required:             std::ops::FnMut<({float}, (&&str, &&str))>
```

It also says `(expected &str, found str)`. This is because you have a slice of string slices (`&[&str]`). The iterator of a slice returns references to each element, so the value is of type `&&str`. The function accepts a `&str`, so that's a mismatch.

On the flip side, the [documentation for `fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) shows what it expects:

```
fn fold<B, F>(self, init: B, f: F) -> B 
    where F: FnMut(B, Self::Item) -> B
```

In words: `fold` takes an iterator by value (`self`), an initial value of some type (`init: B`), and a function `(f: F`). The function takes that type, an iterator value, and returns the type (`FnMut(B, Self::Item) -> B`).

Working backwards, you want to return a `Result`, so `B` must be fixed to that. That means your accumulator must be a `Result`, presumably you want an `Ok`, otherwise we will have failed from the start. Let's do the direct implementation of that:

```
fn calculate_result() -> Result<f64, SaleError> {
    let q_coms = ["1", "2", "3"];
    let v_un_coms = ["1", "2", "3"];
    let pairs = q_coms.iter().zip(v_un_coms.iter());
    pairs.fold(Ok(0.0), |acc, (a, b)| {
        match acc {
            Ok(old) => mult_and_sum(old, (a, b)),
            other => other,
        }
    })
}
```

Which can be simplified with [`and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then)

```
pairs.fold(Ok(0.0), |acc, (a, b)| 
    acc.and_then(|old| mult_and_sum(old, (a, b)))
)
```

And then *maybe* a bit smaller as:

```
let pairs = q_coms.iter().cloned().zip(v_un_coms.iter().cloned());
pairs.fold(Ok(0.0), |acc, i| acc.and_then(|old| mult_and_sum(old, i)))
```

We use [`cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) to convert the `&&str` to a `&str`, but you could also change the function to accept a `&&str`.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the `test` function can fail, how can I use fold with a `Result` return value so if it fails, [if one element is an `Err`]?

Your accumulator (the thing that is "changed" in each iteration) just needs to be a `Result` as well! Look at this code:

```
let q_coms = ["1", "2", "3"];
let v_un_coms = ["1", "2", "3"];

q_coms.iter()
    // We don't need to call `iter()` on `v_un_coms`, because `zip()`
    // takes an argument which implements `IntoIterator`
    .zip(&v_un_coms)

    // As you can see: the starting value is `Ok(0.0)` to say: so far, 
    // there was no error.
    .fold(Ok(0.0), |acc, (a, b)| {
        // The `and_then()` method calls the given closure when the `acc`
        // (the outer one) is `Ok`. The inner `acc` represents the `Ok` 
        // value. The closure will then return another `Result`.
        acc.and_then(|acc| {
            // More fun with `and_then()` and `map()`. Read docs for more
            // information.
            test::<f64>(a)
                .and_then(|a| test::<f64>(b).map(|b| a * b))
                .map(|new_product| acc + new_product)
        })
    })
```

([Try it on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c0ca03e12a383cad1ce935f842d15d79&version=stable&backtrace=0))